# Different function behavior based on params

Tags: javascript, optimization, parameters

I'm new to jQuery/Javascript, so I'm not sure if this is possible. 
I've got a simple function that removes elements, adds a class and disables an input button:

```
function removeElements() {
  $("#dragAndDropFiles, placeHolderImage").remove();
  $(".dragDropTag, .dragDrop, .dragDropIcon, #multiUpload").addClass("dropped");
  $("#multiUpload").prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Later on I will need to essentially reverse this function (ie. add all the elements back in, remove the class, and enable the input button. I could do this by adding another function:

```
function addElements() {
  $("#dragAndDropFiles, placeHolderImage").append('<div>markup here</div>');
  $(".dragDropTag, .dragDrop, .dragDropIcon, #multiUpload").removeClass("dropped");
  $("#multiUpload").prop('disabled', false);
}
```

My question is, can this be optimized somehow, so I won't have to write two functions? For example could I wrap it into one function with less duplication? (e.g. instead of rewriting the same lines for adding/removing classes or enabling/disabling input fields, to have one line of code that does different things based on parameters that get passed in?)

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, you can do something like that :

```
function setElements(remove) {
  var dropIds = $("#dragAndDropFiles, placeHolderImage");
  var dropClasses = $(".dragDropTag, .dragDrop, .dragDropIcon, #multiUpload");

  if (remove) {
    dropIds.remove();
    dropClasses.addClass("dropped");
  } else {
    dropIds.append('<div>markup here</div>');
    dropClasses.removeClass("dropped");
  }

  $("#multiUpload").prop('disabled', remove);
}
```